# What is meant by cpu slack?

Tags: multithreading, performance, concurrency, performance-testing, java.util.concurrent

The following is an excerpt from the book Java Concurrency in Practice, Chapter 12.2 *Testing for Performance* where the author talks about throughput of a bounded buffer implementation.

> Figure 12.1 shows some sample results on a 4-way machine, using buffer
>   capacities of 1, 10, 100, and 1000. We see immediately that a buffer
>   size of one causes very poor throughput; this is because each thread
>   can make only a tiny bit of progress before blocking and waiting for
>   another thread. Increasing buffer size to ten helps dramatically, but
>   increases past ten offer diminishing returns.
>
> It may be somewhat puzzling at first that adding a lot more threads
>   degrades performance only slightly. The reason is hard to see from the
>   data, but easy to see on a CPU performance meter such as perfbar while
>   the test is running: even with many threads, not much computation is
>   going on, and most of it is spent blocking and unblocking threads. So
>   there is plenty of CPU slack for more threads to do the same thing
>   without hurting performance very much.
>
> However, be careful about concluding from this data that you can
>   always add more threads to a producer-consumer program that uses a
>   bounded buffer. This test is fairly artificial in how it simulates the
>   application; the producers do almost no work to generate the item
>   placed on the queue, and the consumers do almost no work with the item
>   retrieved. If the worker threads in a real producer-consumer
>   application do some nontrivial work to produce and consume items (as
>   is generally the case), then this slack would disappear and the
>   effects of having too many threads could be very noticeable. The
>   primary purpose of this test is to measure what constraints the
>   producer-consumer handoff via the bounded buffer imposes on overall
>   throughput.

[image]

What does the author mean by *cpu slack* here? Why will the throughput degrade not degrade more and more as  more number of threads are being added? I am not following the reasoning given by the author regarding the *slight* degradation of performance while adding more and more threads , assuming that the bound on the buffer size is kept constant.

**Edit**: I can think of one reason :since in this case no real work is being done by threads , so the classic problem of increased traffic on shared memory bus, number of cache misses due to context switching of threads are not playing a major role as more and more threads are being added. The situation is going to change once the threads start doing some more work. Is that what the author is trying to convey here in the third paragraph?

Answer (score 1):

There is no formal term such as CPU slack.  The author simply means that the CPU is not fully utilised in doing meaningful work because most time is spent waiting to successfully acquire a mutually exclusive lock.  The author is calling the unused capacity of the CPU, the CPU slack.

NOTE: The associated code tests a multiple producer / multiple consumer scenario, with an equal number of producers and consumers.

EDIT: In the later discussion they talk about the effect of adding more threads if a) the threads do almost no work, and b) the threads occupy the CPU substantially for every produced or consumed item.  I will try to explain the difference with some slightly artificial scenarios.

Suppose that locking takes 1 time unit actively, and 8 time units passively by waiting.  Passive waiting does not occupy the CPU.

**Case 1: Producer-Consumer cost is 1 time unit.**

So we currently account for 2 time units of CPU time, with an
additional 8 time units of passive waiting time.  So we have 8/10
available CPU time units.

If we now want to double the number of threads, we need to accommodate
an additional 2 time units (1 for producer-consumer stuff, and 1 for
active locking time).  That would eat into our supply of available CPU
time -- but we have enough.

**Case 2: Producer-Consumer cost is 11 time units.**

So we currently account for 11+1=12 time units of CPU time, with an additional 8 time units of passive waiting time.  So we have 8/20 available CPU time units.

If we now want to double the number of threads, we need to accommodate an additional 12 time units (11 for producer-consumer stuff, and 1 for active locking time).  That goes beyond the available CPU time units.  Something has to give -- so waiting time will increase, and throughput will suffer.

So in case 2, the amount of real work reduces the amount of time available for new threads, thereby increasing the observed effect of locking contention on the throughput.  It would have been nice if they had also included figures for this imagined scenarios in the book.  It would have made their hand-wavy argument easier to follow.

Comment: please see the update. There is second part to this question also.

Answer (score -1):

I think cpu slack is the resource. According to Wikipedia, it is referred to the amount of time left after a job if the job was started now.
Plenty of cpu slack means much computation resources. When Consumer/Producer do something nontrivial, cpu slack decreases and impacts throughput.

Comment: Does that mean if producer-consumer cost and lock time are more than passive waiting time, throughput will suffer ?